# kivy : O termo 'kivy' não é reconhecido como nome de cmdlet, função, arquivo de script ou programa operável

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-kivy, kivy

Ao tentar rodar o script

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

class TelaLogin(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TelaLogin, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2
        self.add_widget(Label(text='Usuário'))
        self.username = TextInput(multiline=False) 
        self.add_widget(self.username)
        self.add_widget(Label(text='Senha'))
        self.password = TextInput(password=True, multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.password)
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return TelaLogin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Para executar o comando coloco > **kivy main.py**

recebo o seguinte erro

```
kivy : O termo 'kivy' não é reconhecido como nome de cmdlet, função, arquivo de script ou programa operável. Verifique a grafia do nome ou, se um caminho tiver     
sido incluído, veja se o caminho está correto e tente novamente.
No linha:1 caractere:1
+ kivy main.py
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (kivy:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Está usando Windows, certo? O Kivy foi instalado em um virtualenv? Qual versão vc está usando? Seguiu o procedimento de instalação [daqui](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-windows.html)? E a versão do Python? Parece que é suportado até o Python 3.7, veja [aqui](https://kivy.org/#download)

Comment: Segui os procedimentos do kivy.org e consegui usar ele a partir do cmd, oque ja é uma coisa boa.
Tive que instalar o Python 3.6 por que o kivy só suporta desse pra baixo

Comment: Ainda com erro?

Comment: O erro só acontece quando eu tento executar pelo VSCode, porem estou conseguindo quando eu executor pelo CMD

Comment: O interpretador no VS Code deve estar apontando para outra versão de Python.

Answer (score 0):

Bom pelo que entendi, você escreveu seu código e tentou rodar o script principal no cmd com `kivy main.py`, certo?

Para esclarecer a dúvida dos comentário primeiro, o Kivy 2.0.0 suporta as seguintes versões do Python: [3.6 - 3.9](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/gettingstarted/installation.html)

Agora vamos resolver seu problema, precisamos saber se você estiva com o Kivy instalado corretamente. Para testar digite esse comando no cmd `python -m kivy`.

depois você receberá algumas informações e dentre elas estarão essas:

1. **[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.0.0**
2. **[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.9.7**

Pronto, você já sabe a sua versão do Kivy e a do Python. Se alguma dessas informações estiverem incorretas, você pode atualizar e depois continuar o processo.

Depois de tudo estar correto, vamos entender como que se inicia um arquivo `.py` no cmd:

```
python (local_do_arquivo ou nome do arquivo se você ja estiver na pasta)
```

exemplo: `python main.py`